# Filtering iteratevely through data table in R

Tags: r, loops, filter

I have a data table with 3 variables, 1 frequency column, and I am wishing to add another proportion column.

The variable 1 has 4 unique values.
Variable 2 has 5,
And Variable 3 has 2.

[image]

The frequencies captures the amount of times that happens.
But if I add the prop.table to it, it will calculate the proportion regarding the whole data.table, when I really want it to calculate the proportion in the subsets of Variable 2.

I thought of iterating, but it seems complicated in tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `aggregate` function (or tapply) to sum all the counts within the categories of variable 2, then use `prop.table` or similar on the result.

If you want to use the tidyverse instead of base R then this would be a `group_by` followed by `summarise` to add within each group, then `prop_table` again to calculate the proportions.

Comment: An alternative tidyverse solution would be to `pivot_longer` to make the data frame tidy before calculating the summary. If zero-frequency categories had to be included, you would need a final `expand()` or similar.